# Headset not being detected after upgrading from Ubuntu 22.04 to 22.10

Tags: sound, usb, pulseaudio, 22.04, 22.10

I have a HyperX Cloud II USB headset and after upgrading today it isnt being detected. I don't have a dedicated soundcard in my PC. Anyone know what the issue is?

I have tried:

- Booting with it unplugged then plugging in after
- Installed pulseaudio and it isn't being detected there
- Plugging it into a different USB port
- Booting into an older kernel version